# Find the value of a determinant in which the entries are in Harmonic Progression

Tags: determinant

Consider $9$ terms $a_1,a_2 \cdots a_9$ in Harmonic Progression with $a_4=5,a_5=4$. Find the value of the  determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\\a_4&5&4\\
a_7&a_8&a_9\end{vmatrix}$$ The 'not so good ' method is clear, calculating the terms and then evaluating, but I want to ask if there exists a beautiful or elegant solution. Something I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: $a_1(5a_9 - 4a_8) - a_2*(a_4a_9-4a_7)+a_3(a_4a_8-5a_7)$

Comment: Yeah, this is the 'not so good' method. The calculation is highly tedious. Please give some elegant solution.

Comment: What does H.P mean?

Comment: Did you mean $\begin{vmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\\5&4&a_6\\
a_7&a_8&a_9\end{vmatrix}$ ? Else $a_1 = \infty$.